# How to use the Mean Value Theorem to show the continuity of a case-defined function?

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let 
>   $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}, \quad x\neq 0$$
>   $$f(x)=1, \quad x=0$$
>   Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

I have no problem with showing $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ but I have no idea how to do so using the mean value theorem, any help is really appreciated!

Mean Value Theorem:

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Comment: If you write the expression for $f(x),\, x\neq 0$ as $$\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0},$$ does that make the application of the mean value theorem more easily seen?

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: let $g(x) = e^x$.  Apply MVT to $g$ on the interval $[0,x]$.

Comment: probably they don't want you to apply the MVT to $f$, because the hypothesis of the MVT requires that $f$ is at least continuous at $0$ however you slice it.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)=e^x$, then $f(x) = \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}=g'(c)$. Now what do you know about derivatives of $g$?